# Do named weapons function better than their unamed counterparts?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I recently had a dwarf name a weapon (a no quality steel battle axe).  This weapon now shows up in my artifact list, though with a different color than mood/crafted artifacts.

Does the weapon get any bonus for being so named, or is it effectively still a no quality steel battle axe?

If it gets a bonus, how does it compare to artifact weapons, and weapons of other quality levels?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Axe does not become any better by being named, it is just a storytelling thing.

What it means, essentially, is that the weapon in question has become famous for some reason, probably meaning that it isn't quite as no-quality as you might have expected.

But all in all, it's "just" a name, with no combat effect. (Considering the absurdly large amount of bookkeeping being done behind the scenes, it is quite possible that the axe has certain non-combat attributes, such as making the owner happy, or possibly the maker.)

Comment: I don't think the maker is tracked for sub-masterwork items, but a named (otherwise ordinary) weapon will still make the owner much happier (compared to an ordinary owned item) every time he sees and/or wields it. Of course, if you try to take it away or destroy it, it will make him much more depressed than taking away an ordinary owned item, as well. Otherwise, you're correct, receiving a name does not change the combat properties of an item, although I think it does make it immune to fire (like all artifacts).

Comment: @PaulZ: This is Dwarf Fortress; of course the maker is tracked. ;) (Well, maybe, maybe not. Vegas odds are 50/50.)